# Displayed Date is different from data in Django

Tags: python, django, datetime

I am having trouble with displaying the correct date on my django app

For example

In my database, it is stored as `2013-05-03 22:20:01-07`

When I call it in the template by using `{{ task.dateadded }}`, it is displayed as `May 3, 2013, 10:20 p.m`.

When I call it in the template by using `{{ task.dateadded|date:"d" }}`, it is displayed as `03`

And that's correct, HOWEVER

When I call it in the template by using `{{ task.dateadded.day }}`, it is displayed as `4`

It obviously isn't the 4th yet, but it displayed it as it being the 4th.

I am having trouble with this because in the calender I am modifying

```
def group_by_day(self, tasks):
    field = lambda task: task.dateadded.day
    return dict(
        [(day, list(items)) for day, items in groupby(tasks, field)]
    )
```

it would give me the wrong date

I tested around, and found that when it is past 5pm, my date would automatically be "rounded up" to the next date

I have already changed my setting in django

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Canada/Pacific'
```

Is there something about the timezone that I forgot to configure?
Thanks!

Comment: Yes! :) You're conclusion is exactly right! https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/

Comment: I have already changed my timezone to TIME_ZONE = 'Canada/Pacific'  is there something else I am missing?